# Extreme Sport: Fishing

Tags: humans, technological-development, dinosaurs, robots, fishing

A small IT company decided to launch an epic advertizing campaign to increase its branding decided to hold a fishing contest. Participant of all ages and professions are welcome preferably those with robotic background and unafraid of height. Set in the mid 22nd century AD advancement in genes splicing achieved a historic breakthrough and scientists using the latest bio-genetic technology to bring back an adult Mosasaurus. However this particular species is genetically different from the actual specimen from the late Cretaceous period, with a length reaching 30 meters weighting at approximately 18-20 tons it is truly a monster that rules the ocean.
And no this isn't an animatronic but a larger than life predator that put dolly the sheep strapped onto the back of a full grown adult whaleshark to shame.

Each participant will be issued an specially designed exoskeleton and a durable fishing rod, they will be flown over the hot spot in the South China Sea where the fishing contest begins.

My question is what is the minimum specs for the robotic exoskeleton and the fishing rod in order to fish out the Mosasaurus? Most importantly how will public reacts to the sudden introduction of a living fossil?

Condition: The rule is quite simple do not harm the Mosasaurus and your team may only elect a member to disguise himself/herself as bait to lure out the target in the open sea but he/she must not cause the target to choke doing so will result in the entire team being disqualified.

Comment: Are you planning on restricting line strength as normal for fishing competitions? The international big games heavy tackle limits breaking strength to 10-57 kg. For comparison, largest game fish ever captured was 707.61 kg.

Comment: @Gary Walker no need to restrict the line strength at least not with this monster.

Comment: RIP South china Sea food chain

Comment: So a human being is the bait? Do they get an exoskeleton? How do you act as bait?

Comment: @depperm yes they must don the standard issued exoskeleton and once the volunteer is lowered into the water they must wriggle hard to attract the target the suit will also lits up maybe flashing sporadically but the reward is definitely worth it.

Comment: @IanAuld no worry the ecosystem won't collapse soon at least not in our lifetime lol.

Comment: I think you would need more than an exoskeleton to be the bait. Any squishy bits you have exposed run the risk of being punctured by what I imagine is a 2-3 foot long tooth.

Comment: @IanAuld sorry you have to make do with that we'be tried lowering an adult African elephant into the water but that stupid animal just swam to shore pulling our towing boat along at 10000 knot per hour!

Comment: You're aware that's 11507.8 mph?

Comment: @IanAuld sometime when to put all your heart into it just like that elephant nothing is impossible!

Comment: The speed of sound is ~761 mph for reference.

Comment: @IanAuld forgot to mention we came up with a king sized exoskeleton for the elephant breaking a sound barrier is just a peanut you should see the look on Mosasaurus while it is giving chase.

Comment: If your exoskeletons can accelerate the ungainly elephant to super sonic speeds I don't think you need the rod. Just jump in and drag the thing out.

Comment: @IanAuld you should see the look on the elephant face! anyway this is a fishing contest all anglers must abide by the rules. I need minimum specs for the exoskeleton any recommendations?

Comment: What do the competitors have underneath them? A boat, an island, or are they just swimming?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh since this is the future so a spaceship or flying aircraft carrier hovering above the open water. No worry the transports can hold hundreds maybe thousands of people and still have sufficient space to squeeze in a 20 tons trophy.

Comment: you said this was a small IT company? how can they pull something like this off (this sounds like a massive contest)? The insurance alone will be thousands, and the equipment....

Comment: Does it matter that a mososaur is not *fish*?  It's a reptile.  I don't know off hand if it would be Kosher.

Comment: @JDlugosz actually it is a hybrid using DNA from certain fishs and reptiles.

Comment: Sure they mix? Reptile is already beyond fish, so it already knows all that. You don't mix in more ancestral form because it's aquatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this Mosasaur is the size of a whale (and with a considerably nastier disposition), I don't see that fishing in the ordinary sense is even possible, exoskeleton or no.

The length of the line and the breaking strength are two issues already discussed in the comments; you would need to "hook" the monster with multiple lines to distribute the strain and keep control even if one or more lines broke. Lines would have to be made out of something very strong, perhaps a super material like Spectrashield ultra-high-molecular-weight polyethylene (UHMWPE), or synthetic Spider silk (which has a tensile strength 17 times greater than steel on a weight for weight basis).

The other issue is "baiting" the hook. The Mosasaur is the top predator of its age, and at the size you are describing, would need to consume a whale in order to supply the energy for its metabolism. A wiggling human on the end of a line would not even qualify as "finger food", and unless the South China sea has already been swept of all the available food by the monster, it would probably ignore such a small offering.

As a practical matter, setting up a giant net to drop on the Mosasaur once it has been lured by a whale or giant school of tuna or something similar may be the only way to go for this scenario. As a BTW, even a "real" Mosasaur would be a pretty extreme catch, and most of the considerations would still exist if only on a smaller scale.

Comment: I hate to admit but you are right.

Comment: If they can engineer or de-extinct a mososaur, I think carbon nanotube filliment would be available by then, too. UHMW-PE is *so* twentieth century!